# Duplicate Symbol in _main

Tags: iphone, build-error

Can someone tell me why I am getting this error.  I have tried cleaning and building several times . But still I am getting this error.

```
duplicate symbol _main in:
/Users/outthinkingindiapvtltd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PatternTest-     axdlojadtjwkbvdioeiumrzlovix/Build/Intermediates/PatternTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/PatternTest.build/Objects-normal/armv7/main-EC3660AC7D58737D.o
/Users/outthinkingindiapvtltd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PatternTest-axdlojadtjwkbvdioeiumrzlovix/Build/Intermediates/PatternTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/PatternTest.build/Objects-normal/armv7/main-6C8789F4078B135A.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

This means, you have a file twice in your Xcode Project. Check the Project folder, You will find a file in two different groups or folders with the same name.

Comment: Its showing main-EC3660AC7D58737D.o and main-6C8789F4078B135A.o are duplicate . But where I need to delete these. I am not getting.

Comment: These are not the filenames, You have to look manually for the files in the project folder. There may be a duplicate or you can check for the Targets/Compiled Sources for any duplicate entries.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have multiple entries under Targets/Compiled Sources. removed them and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible you have imported an .m file instead of .h, like:

```
#import "DemoView.m"
```

Just check the extensions of the file you recently imported, after which you are getting this error.